# How do I discard all changes in smartgit?

Tags: git, smartgit

I new to git. And using git with UI(smartgit). My manager said me to discard all changes.I saw this command

> git stash save --keep-index

But is there any corresponding button in smartgit?

Comment: I have never seen smartgit but I was able to find manual for it: http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Manual

Comment: [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) does not only discard the changes but also put them aside, to be restored later, if needed. [`git checkout -f`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) discard the changes. You should start by reading the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *uncommitted* files, you can discard your changes by selecting the changed files you want to discard, right click and select "Discard..."  Or just select and hit Ctrl+Z.

[image]

This is one of my favorite features of SmartGit.

Comment: My issue is that we use submodules and discard fails because it needs to be forced.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is **Local | Save Stash** in SmartGit. You can add it to the toolbar, if you like (right-click the toolbar, select *Configure*).

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to use a git shell. I downloaded it together with github program. 
I went into directory of that project and and executed commands provided in second comment.
 This solved my problem.